# C++ - Class members when Destructor is called during overwrite

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, overwrite

im trying to understand the order of Constructor and Destructor calls when overwriting an object.

My code is :

```
class A 
{
public: 
   A(int n): x(n)
   { cout << "A(int " << n << ") called" << endl; }

   ~A( )
   { cout << "~A( ) with A::x = " << x << endl; }

private: 
   int x; 
};

int main( ) 
{
    cout << "enter main\n"; 
    int x = 14;  
    A z(11); 
    z = A(x); 
    cout << "exit main" << endl; 
}
```

--

The output is :

```
enter main
A(int 11) called
A(int 14) called
~A( ) with A::xx = 14
exit main
~A( ) with A::xx = 14
```

--

Why is A::xx = 14 when the destructor is called? Shouldn't it be 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should it be 11? You reassign `z` to `A(14)`, so it's 14 at the end.

(After your edit: You also see the destructor of the temporary `A(14)` object that gets destroyed at the end of the assignment.)

Comment: But the first printing of x happens during the destructor, so if the first instance of A hasn't been destroyed yet, shouldn't x still be 11

Comment: You realize that each object keeps a separate copy of the member variable? You don't have a reference or a static, just an ordinary member.

Comment: The first `~A( ) with A::xx = 14` is the destructor of the temporary, because it has finished changing `z` to be 14.  Then main ends, and `z` is destructed, showing the second `~A( ) with A::xx = 14`.